# using a param of a resulting method in main method

Tags: java

If I have a method e.g.

```
public int addition(int x, int y) 
{
 int z = x + y
 return z; 
}

 public int usez(int z)
  {
    // TODO
  }


 public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
classname d = new classname();
d.usez(z)...
}
```

z is not readable. So, is there a way to make the resulting z from the first method into the usez method when testing it in main =/

hopefully this makes some sense! in a real version e.g. if x,y = 1,2 then z = 3 I want the main method to recognise z to be 3.

Answer (score 0):

`z` is a private local variable for the method addition. You can't and should not attempt to access it. However, it's value is returned by the function it's defined in (`addition`). Therefor, you can do the following:

```
classname d = new classname();
int zValue = d.addition(1,2);
d.usez(zValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all methods including `main()` are in same class, You can make z as class member variable as

```
int z= 0;
```

and assign value to it in

```
public int addition(int x, int y) 
    {
     z = x + y
     return z; 
    }
```

and use in `usez(z)`.

```
     public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
    classname d = new classname();
    d.usez(z)...
    }
```